# python's gi module is not compatible with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run a python (version 3.6.2) program that also uses the "gi" module.
When I try to import the "gi", it gives me the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
    print url
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

The only thing that I do is to import it.

```
import gi
```

Comment: No, your problem is the `print` syntax changed from 2.x to 3.x.  `print` now requires parentheses since it is now a function.

Comment: @amone so what am I supposed to do? I am not the one who call the print function?

Comment: how did you install the `gi` module?

Comment: Generally in such situations, you could ask the package author to adapt their code for Python 3, or use their source code to fix the problem & contribute the fix back. Here, the package seems old and the PyPI link to the project source at GIthub is a 404. You can still try a local fix, or try using Python 2.7.x, or try to achieve the same aims without using that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool **2to3** is an [Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), you can get over a ride throw the old python and making the changes work into python 3, I make a simple example like this:

I created this file, python2.py:

```
#!python3

print 5
```

when I run it with python it obviously shows:

```
line 3
    print 5          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

so, you can transform it via terminal like this:

> **This is the important comand**

```
$ 2to3 -w home/path_to_file/python2.py
```

-w parameter will write the file, if you want only see the future changes without apply them, just run it without -w.
 after run it it will show something like

```
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
RefactoringTool: Refactored Desktop/stackoverflow/goto.py
--- Desktop/stackoverflow/goto.py   (original)
+++ Desktop/stackoverflow/goto.py   (refactored)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 #!python3

-print 5
+print(5)
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
```

And the file will look like:

```
#!python3

print(5)
```

Comment: I didn't try this tool but it seems it does exactly what I've done by hand. "gi" is a small module so it didn't take too long for me to make this change manually but yes this tool looks like a good solution for this kind of problem.